# How do I modify this colored Mesh in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have this nifty glowing ring in an EPS file. I am trying to figure out how to use Illustrator to have the same blue ring with a white background.

[image: final]

I'm having difficulty understanding where the black background comes from. I know that the layout of the file is a number of overlapping circles, then a single mesh that results in the final output. When the Mesh is hidden:

[image: mesh disabled]
[image]

On that Mesh, I think the blue color is controlled through the "Recolor Artwork" dialog
[image]

Knowing now how the effect is constructed, how would I go about having the same blue effect with a white background?

Comment: Recolor Artwork is **not** an effect. All it does is actually *recolor* something -- the same as if you were to select it and change the fill/stroke color in the Color panel. It's difficult to say how the file is constructed without seeing the actual file. My best guess is there are some blending modes being used. However, you haven't shown the entire layers panel in any of your screenshots or any area which would confirm that.

Comment: FYI, when you open the Recolor Artwork dialog, it's merely showing you the *current* color, not any "effect".

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it would be by inverting colors.
First expand artwork.

select the artwork >Edit >Edit Colors>Invert colors

This way your black areas become white.
But you will have to recolor artwork after, since colors other than black and white turn into other colors on inverting .

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to tell exactly but I'm almost 100% sure that you should look into Appearance panel (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>) or (Window>Appearance), and check blending modes.

Without examining file it will be hard to tell :)